# Formatting data in array with objects

Tags: javascript, array

I am formatting a data result from the array of objects that looks like this:

```
const data = {
  periods: [{
    month: 'January',
    sickLeave: {
        differance: '-12000',
        revision: '6000',
        paid: '18000',
    },
    holidayLeave: {
        differance: '10000',
        revision: '22000',
        paid: '12000',
    },
    received: '-2000',
    taken: '2000',
    result: '0',
  },
  {
    month: 'Februar',
    sickLeave: {
        differance: '-8000',
        revision: '6000',
        paid: '18000',
    },
    holidayLeave: {
        differance: '10000',
        revision: '22000',
        paid: '12000',
    },
    received: '-2000',
    taken: '2000',
    result: '0',
  }],
};
```

What I want to do with this is to make a new array that looks like this:

```
[{
  name: "sickLeaveDifferance",
  result:  ["-12000", "-8000"]
},
{
  name: "sickLeaveRevision",
  result: ["6000", "6000"]
},
{
  name: "sickLeavePaid",
  result: ["18000", "18000"]
},
{
  name: "holidayLeaveDifferance",
  result: ["10000", "10000"]
},
{
  name: "holidayLeaveRevision",
  result: ["22000", "22000"]
},
{  
  name: "holidayLeavePaid",
  result: ["12000", "12000"]
},
{
  name: "received",
  result: ["-2000", "-2000"]
},
{ 
  name: "taken",
  result: ["2000", "2000"]
},
{
  name: "result",
  result: ["0", "0"]
}]
```

I am achieving this with this function:

```
const formattedResult = perioder => {
  let resultArray = [];
  const pushNewValue = (key, value) => {
    const objectExists = resultArray.find(e => e.name === key);
    if (objectExists) {
      objectExists.result.push(value)
    } else {
      resultArray.push({
        name: key,
        result: [value]
      })
    }
  };

  perioder.map(el => 
   Object.entries(el).forEach(([key, value]) => {
     if (key != 'month') {
       if (key === 'sickLeave' || key === 'holidayLeave') {
         const prop = key;
         Object.entries(value).forEach(([key, value]) => {
           const name = `${prop + key[0].toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)}`;
           pushNewValue(name, value);
         })
       } else {
         pushNewValue(key, value);
       }
     }
   }))

   return resultArray;
}
```

But, I feel like there is a better, more elegant way of achieving this, just not sure how to do this?

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mb5hz36a/).

Answer (score 1):

Do you really anticipate the data model changing so much that this needs to be ultra flexible?  In order to do so the code is quite complex - for instance having a forEach inside of an if inside of a forEach inside of a map.  You already have model specific checks in the code anyways, such as the check for the 'sickLeave' and 'holidayLeave' keys.  I think a solution along these lines would be perfectly acceptable:

```js
const initialNormalizedVals = {
  "sickLeaveDifferance": [],
  "sickLeaveRevision": [],
  "sickLeavePaid": [],
  "holidayLeaveDifferance": [],
  "holidayLeaveRevision": [],
  "holidayLeavePaid": [],
  "received": [],
  "taken": [],
  "result": [],
}

const normalizedData = data.periods.reduce((outcome, { sickLeave, holidayLeave, received, taken, result }) => {
  outcome.sickLeaveDifferance.push(sickLeave.differance)
  outcome.sickLeaveRevision.push(sickLeave.revision)
  outcome.sickLeavePaid.push(sickLeave.paid)
  outcome.holidayLeaveDifferance.push(holidayLeave.differance)
  outcome.holidayLeaveRevision.push(holidayLeave.revision)
  outcome.holidayLeavePaid.push(holidayLeave.paid)
  outcome.result.push(result)
  outcome.taken.push(taken)
  outcome.received.push(received)

  return outcome
}, initialNormalizedVals)

const transformedData = Object.keys(normalizedData).map(key => {
  return {
    name: key,
    result: normalizedData[key],
  }
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your answer looks good, enjoy your stay!